# Select a number in a div tag and subtract it from 59 and display the result in text

Tags: javascript

I am trying to select a price listed by class "ProductPrice" and subtract it from $59 to display a free shipping message but cannot get it to select the product price. Where am I going wrong?

```
<div><em class="ProductPrice">$16.95</em></div>


<script>
var cart = document.getElementByClassName("ProductPrice").replace('$', '');
var test = 59 - cart;

document.write('<div>Add $' + cart + 'to your cart to get free shipping.</div>');

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are selecting the DOM element which class is `ProductPrice` and you then try to use the `replace` function on it. But the problem is that the replace function is a method from the `String` class.

So you should first get the string value of the text contained in the element, which is:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('ProductPrice')[0].textContent.replace('$', '')
```

You could also use the `innerHTML` property which would get you the HTML code instead of the text value.

Also, as you can see, the function is [`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) and it returns an array of all elements with this class.

Finally, you might want to display a correct number of decimals in the resulting `test` variable with the help of the [`Number.toFixed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) method.

EDIT: Javascript should be smart enough to cast the string to a `Number` before doing the math, but in case you want to make sure, you can use [`parseFloat(string)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) to get the floating point number value of the string.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things to keep in mind.

- You should use `getElementsByClassName` instead of `getElementByClassName`.
- Access the particular element with bracket notation. To get the first element, append `[0]`
- Call `innerHTML` before replace.

```html
<div><em class="ProductPrice">$16.95</em></div>


<script>
var cart = document.getElementsByClassName("ProductPrice")[0].innerHTML.replace('$', '');
var promotion = 59 - cart;

document.write('<div>Add $' + promotion + ' to your cart to get free shipping.</div>');

</script>
```

Edit: It's probably better to use `textContent` instead of `innerHTML`.

Comment: I assume you don't have to parse here because it's int - string, so the string gets autoparsed?

Comment: Correct, because of JS type conversion

Comment: Would it be a best practice to do it anyway, since the opposite, `var promotion  = cart + 59` would be incorrect? Or can we assume everyone knows this?

Answer (score 0):

Your answer would be:

```
var cart = parseFloat(document.getElementsByClassName("ProductPrice")[0].innerHTML);
var test = 59 - cart;
document.write('<div>Add $' + cart + 'to your cart to get free shipping.</div>');
```

`parseFloat` takes in a string value as a parameter and converts it into a float starting from the first number and continuing until it reaches a non-number. For example, your `$16.95` (string) would become `16.95` (number). Also, `getElementsByClassName` returns an array of all elements with the class name `"ProductPrice"` so you will have to reference the first index in that array. Hope this helps!

Comment: parseInt turns 16.95 into 16. Use parseFloat.

Comment: Great catch! `parseFloat` works with decimal places, which is ideal for monetary values. Fixed my mistake.

Comment: For the record, you shouldn't work with floats when representing money, since every cent counts and float multiplication or division isn't exact in JS. So the best method would be to multiple the flaot with 100, then parseInt, and divide the end result again by 100, so that all calculatiosn are done in integers.